# python flask: asynchronous requests

Tags: python, flask, requests-futures

In a flask view I receive data via an API call and this data has to be passed to an external API that is sometimes very slow.

So I want the view to return a positive status code while the request is being handled async.

I have tried with requests-futures and have difficulties with the callback:

```
def bg_cb(sess, resp):
    print(resp.text)

@app.route('/incomingdata', methods=['POST',])
def clients():

    (... process incoming POST data and create outgoing API call. here I inserted a demo call to httpbin.org that simulates a very slow API ...)

    from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
    session = FuturesSession()
    future = session.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/3', background_callback=bg_cb)
    response = future.result()

    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'}), 200
```

Unfortunately the above code will wait with the return until the callback has been processed. Here that is 3 seconds.

How can I achieve the result, that the view returns response with 200 immediately and after 3 seconds the callback function is called.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `requests-futures` is not going to help you with a single API call. Also, what would you be returning other than 200 during the 3 second wait?

Comment: Or does the caller only need to know that you received the request, and there is no actual data to return to them?

Comment: exactly. The caller only needs to know the data has been delivered. always 200.

Comment: the callback function will have a lot more business logic...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `result()` if you need just to call something asynchronously. The `result()` method will wait until `background_callback` will be finished. Just an example:

```
def bg_cb(sess, resp):
    print('done')

# in view:
print('call async...')
session.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/3', background_callback=bg_cb)

return jsonify({'status': 'ok'}), 200
```

Call endpoint, you will see response without delay. Console output:

```
call async...
# after few seconds
done
```

Now let's wait until callback will be finished:

```
future = session.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/3', background_callback=bg_cb)
print('wait result...')
response = future.result()
print('after result...')
```

Call endpoint, you will see response with delay. Console output:

```
wait result...
done
after result...
```

So, you don't need `result()` if you need just run something asynchronously.

Also you can use [rq](http://python-rq.org/) or [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) if you need specific asynchronous processing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your code but got runtime error "get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'background_callback'"

Comment: @Zvi try to update `package`.  [check](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) when `background_callback` was added.

Comment: After update got `background_callback` is deprecated and will be removed in 1.0, use `hooks` instead, but the program did not crash this time. Switched to 'hooks' and it worked with no errors or warnings